# RandomNumberGenerator in ASP.NET5

Tags: c#, asp.net, random, cryptography

I have created a new Web API project using the ASP.NET 5 Templates. I am wanting to generate random numbers using System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator but it is not available in the .NET Platform 5.4 (see screenshot).

[image: Error Message]

Compiling it also generates the following errors:

```
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Cryptography' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'RandomNumberGenerator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   CS0103  The name 'RandomNumberGenerator' does not exist in the current context
```

Is there a way to use this or is there an alternative random generator that I can use which is cryptographically secure?

Comment: I think all of the Microsoft .Net secure random number generators are in the Cryptography namespace, which it looks like that platform lacks altogether.  You'll probably need to look for a 3rd party library to download.

Comment: Had you take a look to BouncyCastle crypto api for C# ? if you would be indipendent from Microsoft solution that could be an idea,

Comment: I believe you need to include the [System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms) NuGet package. Note: it is still only in pre-release at the time of this writing

Comment: Thanks @ScottChamberlain feel free to create an answer with this and I'll accept it. I had to move the dependency so it was only for dotnet5.4 in the project.json (see my answer).

Comment: Na, I was not confidant in the answer it was only a suggestion to check on. You can give yourself the credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working thanks to Scott Chamberlain's comment by adding the System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms NuGet package.

I also had to modify the project.json so it was only a dependency of dotnet5.4 and not a global dependency otherwise the compiler would complain that RandomNumberGenerator exists in both System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms and mscorlib.