# System.Security.Cryptography not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, cryptography

I am trying to add a reference to System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates but I get: "The type or namespace 'Cryptography' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security'.

I have tried adding System.Security to references, I have tried adding System.Security.dll, I have tried adding mscorlib.dll, I have tried to find how to add Windows.Security.Cryptography.

No luck, therefore I cannot use the X509Certificate2 class, which I need.

Has anyone run into this impossibly frustrating situation?

UPDATE:

Looking at this question, [RandomNumberGenerator in ASP.NET5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34345271/randomnumbergenerator-in-asp-net5)
I cannot find what I am looking for in Nuget. In nuget, I only see System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.Analyzers. I need System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates

Comment: This is not the same....the library I am looking for cannot be found in the Nuget packages.

Comment: Because it did not point to the same package in the duplicate i re-opened the question and provided a link to the NuGet package you need

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: I am using .NET 4.5

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates) NuGet project to your ASP.NET project.

.NET Core (which is what the new ASP.NET uses) is a component based architecture, you need to import the packages of the features you want. When you searched in Visual Studio you likely did not have the "Include Prerelease" option checked so the libraries for .NET Core where filtered out.

Comment: When I search System.Security.Cryptography in Nuget, I can only find System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms.Analyzers

Comment: @KateMak you likely don't have "Include Prerelease" checked. ([unchecked](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KqFTI.png), [checked](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2zcq5.png))

Comment: Apparently I did not have the right release version which is why it was not working.  Thank you for your input!!

Comment: Besides what the solution suggests, I had to remove the binding redirects from .netframework project